# List and image in the same ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to get an image and a list in the same 'scroll' (I don't know how else to put it). My basic (vertical) layout is:

- TextView
- ImageView
- ListView

I'm trying to get the scrolling as if the image is a list item itself. So the textview has to stay in place at the top and everything else has to scroll under it.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_purple"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_app_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/about_app_label"
        android:textColor="@color/background"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/information_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:divider="@drawable/listdivider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >

    <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/row -->
</ListView>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

The custom row layout for the listView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/listview"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="4dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icon_content_description" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_label"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/result_label"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_count"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_label"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_result"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textColorLink="@color/app_purple" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/list_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have a vertical `LinearLayout` holding the fixed `TextView` and the `ListView`. Your `ImageView` would be a header on the `ListView`, added via `addHeaderView()`. Headers, despite their name, scroll with the contents of the `ListView`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what is was looking for. This is the second time you've helped me with this project, first time was through one of your books :).

Answer (score 1):

to make custom list views you need to create a single_list_item.xml file to arrange everything you want to scroll for example the image with a description text next to it. Also you need to add a ListView on your Xml file so the program can process the view. And them, you can process everything on your java file using an adapter. and the the list will appear at the bottom of the text.

There is a great example of how to do it [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: I already have a custom row layout for the listView. But i dont see the possibility to make a imageView take up the entire row. Or is it possible to implement one row with a different layout? I've updated my post with the row.xml code. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: why don't you add the ImageView to the row.xml file and draw it on top of the texts... also in the graphical view of the layout under eclipse you'll see how each row is going to see with the image.

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear what exactly are you trying to do. ScrolView can have only ONE child. so I guess you should put the ImageView and the Listview in a LinearLayout.
but any way - it's a bad idea to put a Listview inside a ScrollView - how would the OS now what are you trying to scroll? the ListItem or the whole list. if you can be more specific - I can try help more...

Comment: I think I have to put the imageView as the first row in the listview but I already have a custom row layout which won't allow that, I added the custom row.xml to the original post. I think my best option is to add the imageView to the listView as a row, but I don't know how to do that with the current row.xml layout.